# Mosquitto broker : fully init?

Tags: initialization, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I would need to fully initialize my mosquitto 1.5.7 broker , to clean all messages stored in the broker memory, all messages counter....
How can I do it ?

The #SYS always get all stored information when I restart with :

```
systemctl restart mosquitto
```

data in #SYS

[image]

If I can initialize the broker,does clients will connect again automatically ? (using their "reconnect process ...")

Thank for your help,

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't clear what you are actually asking here, but to clear all the data from a Mosquitto broker you need to shut it down, then delete the persistence file (the path to this file will be in the mosquitto config file normally found in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`)

Once you have deleted the persistence file restart the broker.

And yes, most clients will reconnect when the broker comes back up, but all their session data will have been lost so they will need to resubscribe to any topics they are interested in.

Comment: @lopic https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks for replying.
Yes, I want to clean all data of the broker.
in my case, persistence file or persistence path are NOT set in the mosquitto.conf, and as I understand in the mosquitto doc, "persistence" is false by default.
So, after a check /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db is empty...

Comment: Assuming that persistence is not enabled in any of the included files, then just restarting the broker will clear all the internal data

Comment: it is what I hope but ... all counters and data of the broker are the same after a restart.

Comment: Have you double checked that the broker is actually restarting? Have you tried just stopping, checking it is stopped, then starting?

Comment: yes:

1) I stoped it : systemctl stop mosquitto

2) check really stop (in syslog)

3) systemctl restart mosquitto